# how to bulk format url with bash command?

Tags: bash, command, iterm2

I have many links in markdown format like this below:

```
[link desc1](http://1goo.....com)
[link desc2](http://2goo.....com)
[link desc3](http://3goo.....com)
[link desc4](http://4goo.....com)
...
```

below is my desired output, remove[] and () just remain links

```
http://1goo.....com
http://2goo.....com
http://3goo.....com
http://4goo.....com
...
```

I just want to save the link，thanks a lot.

Comment: Please add your complete desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you only want to get the URL and all that info is contained in a file named urls.txt, then you'd like to try sed like this:

```
sed -e 's/.*(//' -e 's/)//' urls.txt
```

BR

Regards